# SQL : query for multiple conditions with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to query multiple conditions with multiple columns, like AND clause in AND clause.

**Example data**

```
|   Name   |     Country    |     ZipCode    |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| A        | Italy          | 2020           |
| B        | Japan          | 1010           |
| C        | Canada         | 3030           |
| D        | Japan          | 1011           |
| E        | Japan          | 1012           |
```

The result that I need is without..

- Country = Japan and ZipCode = 1010
- Country = Canada and ZipCode = 3030

```
|   Name   |     Country    |     ZipCode    |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| A        | Italy          | 2020           |
| D        | Japan          | 1011           |
| E        | Japan          | 1012           |
```

I try to write SQL like :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ((Country <> 'Japan' AND ZipCode <> '1010') AND 
 (Country <> 'Canada' AND ZipCode <> '3030'))
```

but it's not correct. Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `not`:

```
where not (country = 'Japan' and ZipCode = '1010' or
           Country = 'Canada' and ZipCode = '3030'
          )
```

You can expand this out of course:

```
where (country <> 'Japan' or ZipCode <> '1010') and
      (country <> 'Canada' or Zipcode <> '3030')
```

Note:  This constructs will also filter out `NULL` values.  There are none in your sample data and they can both be tweaked to handle them if necessary.